# OS-independent API to monitor file system?

Tags: platform-independent, file-monitoring

I would like to experiment with ideas about distributed file synchronization/replication. To make it efficient when the user is working, I would like to implement some kind of daemon to monitor changes in some directory (e.g. /home/user/dirToBeMonitored or c:\docs and setts\user\dirToBeMonitored). So, I could be able to know which filename was added/changed/deleted at every time (or within a reasonable interval).

Is this possible with any high-medium level language?. Do you know some API (and in which language?) to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: OP is asking for a cross-platform solution, none of the answers below address this. Ideally such a solution should be implemented in a low-level language like C++ then provide bindings to various high-level languages ie Python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*A bonified answer, albeit one that requires a largish library dependency (well-worth it IMO)!*

QT provides the [QFileSystemwatcher](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class, which uses the native mechanism of the underlying platform.

Even better, you can use the QT language bindings for Python or Ruby. [Here](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/pyqt4-text-editor-final-changes/) is a simple PyQT4 application which uses [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qfilesystemwatcher.html).

**Notes**

- A good reference on on [creating deployable PyQT4 apps](http://aralbalkan.com/1675), especially on OSX but should work for Windows also.
- Same solution previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253/how-to-be-notified-of-file-directory-change-in-c-c-ideally-using-posix/61300#61300).
- Other cross-platform toolkits may also do the trick (for example [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/)'s [GIO](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/) has [GFileMonitor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/GFileMonitor.html), although it is UNIX only and doesn't support OSX's [FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) mechanism afaik).

Answer (score 10):

The APIs are totally different for [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx), [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents), and any other [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor) you can name, it seems. I don't know of any cross-platform library that handles this in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux it is called [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Answer (score 0):

And on OS X it's called [fsevents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents).  It's an OS-level API, so it's easiest to access from C or C++.  It *should* be accessible from nearly any language, although bindings for your preferred language may not have been written yet.