# Any libraries/modules for file management in python?

Tags: python

Trying to find out if there any good modules which allow constant monitoring of a directory and as soon as a new file is in there, a number of functions are intiated?

Also actions should not be done on partly transfered files which are coming in via FTP.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for file system events modules.

Which OS are you running?

(disclaimer: I'm maintaining those two modules)

- On Linux, you can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). Have a look at [inotify code](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/37042e8b3b34/hgext/inotify/linux) in mercurial.
- On Mac OS X (>=10.5) you can use [FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents). See [pyfsevents](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfsevents).

For other alternatives, you can have a look at [pyinotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial) or [gamin](http://www.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/), but I have never tried those modules.

Comment: Operating system is Linux/Unix , however it should be able to work with unix

Comment: Generic "unix" does not have such functionality; specific Unix versions often do, but you have to specify which versions (Solaris, HPUX, ?BSD, AIX, ...) and with some you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm implementing a cross-platform library called watchdog which
may be what you are looking for. It's available at 
http://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

HTH.
=)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NicDumZ's excellent modules, you may want to consider [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) for a rich (and richly documented) alternative. I think Nic's is simpler (at least for basical functionality), but I haven't studied it in detail -- I'm more familiar with pyinotify. BTW, interestingly, the latter is in pure Python (with `ctypes` of course;-).

Since you did mention "should be able to work with unix", you should specify exactly which unix versions you need to support and study whether they offer similar functionality (and if so through what interface). For example, this [man page](http://ibm5.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?inotify+7) for inotify says:

> The inotify API is Linux specific.  Some other systems provide 
>   similar mechanisms, e.g., FreeBSD has kqueue, and Solaris has /dev/poll.

and Nic already mentioned FSEvents on MacOSX. Once you determine the C way to do it on a given system of interest, worst case, if there's no pre-made Python version, you can probably use `ctypes` similarly to the way pyinotify does for inotify. BTW, for completeness: on Windows you might use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (typically you'd do that via either ctypes or the win32file file of the Win32 Extensions).

Answer (score 0):

High-level libraries often implement different solutions for each platform they work on. With luck, you only have to use one method -- the high-level library.

See [this non-python Question about file monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155490/os-independent-api-to-monitor-file-system)

Specifically, if you can use QT's QFileSystemwatcher with python bindings, or GLib's GFileMonitor (which I use in my application, although it's just for Linux), you might save work.

Comment: I'm digging into glib's file system code (called "gio", also as python module "gio" when part of pygobject), and it has implementations in place for inotify and win32, and "fam" which is a polling fallback http://git.gnome.org/cgit/glib/tree/gio