# How to monitor a directory and read image in this directory in C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, imread

First of all, I am new to C++. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I worked on a project that includes an camera. Camera send an image(bitmap) to a specific folder location in my computer. I want to monitor the directory consistenly. When a new bitmap image is obtained in the directory, I want to process this image. The code that I want to use is always monitoring the directory and read the last bitmap image in this directory. What can I use to achieve it? What is your suggestions? Could you write the source code? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I am processing the image by using the code as follow:
frame = cvLoadImage("test17.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

However; I do not want to read image by typing its name. I want to monitor a directory and when an image is added to the directory, I want to read this image. Does it help you to understand what I tried to do?

Comment: I think it is probably duplicated with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253/how-to-be-notified-of-file-directory-change-in-c-c-ideally-using-posix  and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont agree with the other guy who answered the question, it can be done eaisly with some co-existing libraries that I used below, This code does what you are looking for,

```
string processName()
{

   FILETIME bestDate = { 0, 0 };
   FILETIME curDate;
   string name;
   CFileFind finder;


   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile("*.png");

   while (bWorking)
   {

      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

     // date = (((ULONGLONG) finder.GetCreationTime(ft).dwHighDateTime) << 32) + finder.GetCreationTime(ft).dwLowDateTime;

      finder.GetCreationTime(&curDate);

      if (CompareFileTime(&curDate, &bestDate) > 0 )
      {
          bestDate = curDate;
          name = finder.GetFileName().GetString();
          // name = (LPCTSTR) finder.GetFileName();
      }



   }
   return name;
}
```

Here I wrote it for the code you, it takes the name of the last entered /.png extension you can check libray for it.

Please tell me for further question

Answer (score 1):

The Windows ReadDirectoryChangesW API can be used to monitor a directory for added files. However, it is very advanced and if you are new to C++ and Windows programming it is probably beyond what you can achieve. You will need some experienced help.